# FrameLayout side by side Number Pickers

Tags: java, android

I wish to have two of my number pickers side by side. I cannot get them literally side by side. I have one set to gravity center (feetPicker) and then if I set the other one (inchesPicker) left or right, it goes into the very corner of the dialog box instead of nicely right beside each other.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the number pickers looking nicely side by side with the framelayout using my following code? I am new to Android (java) so any help will be much appreciated :)

Thank you!

```
 @Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT; 

    feetPicker = new NumberPicker(getContext());
    feetPicker.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    inchesPicker = new NumberPicker(getContext());
    inchesPicker.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

    FrameLayout dialogView = new FrameLayout(getContext());
    dialogView.addView(feetPicker);
    dialogView.addView(inchesPicker);

    return dialogView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the layout gravity of each number picker to `LEFT` and `RIGHT`? Like this:

```
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT; // center left

layoutParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT; // center right
```